E2E Testing K8s with Kuttl
I want to test my Kubernetes setup with KUTTL before each deployment for every profile. I am wondering if there is a way to test it in a pipeline as a separate stage. I use Helm charts and the values.yaml file. The goal is to validate the Kubernetes setup before pushing it to production machines. I guess I need a base image with minikube and kuttle. Have anybody a example ?
